# Вызов фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, начал изучать фрагменты, и задался вопросом как сделать так, чтобы фрагмент был открыт сразу при старте приложения, а не при нажатии на кнопку допустим?

Comment: Надо его программно добавить, либо прямо в разметку поместить. 1 вариант - лучше и не несёт с собой сложно устранимых багов. Примерно так: `getFrgamentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, new Fragment(), "test").commit();`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Попользовался своим приложением некоторое время и стал замечать, что при открытии других фрагментов, иногда фрагмент вызванный таким образом вылезает сзади и перекрывает текущий фрагмент как это исправить?